# Visual Studio needs 2 sessions opened to be able to be used?

Tags: visual-studio

I have been using `Visual Studio 2017` for a while, and it turns out that one day it just decided to stop allowing me to do anything on the first instance I open it on.

It can use it normally when I open the second instance of `Visual Studio`, but leaving the first instance open just to eat memory is putting a toll on my computer's process as I am working on quite a heavy website.

Is there any explanation that this happen? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why are you still using RC? It has been released already and received two updates since then.

Comment: @VTT Sorry it's a normal Visual 2017, I didn't quite check my current version as I downloaded it when it was still RC

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have the latest version of VS.
2. If that does not resolve it, edit the csproj file of the offending project, and remove the line containing `E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47`
3. Reopen the solution.